# How to tell at runtime whether an iOS app is running through a Crashlytics Beta install

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

Is there any way to tell at runtime whether an iOS app is running through a Crashlytics Beta install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is detect if the app was produced as an Ad Hoc build.
To do that, add `-DADHOC` to the "other swift flags" of your Ad Hoc build settings, and use

```
#if ADHOC
#endif
```

for the beta-specific code.

Answer (score 2):

Mike from Fabric here. There isn't a public API to capture this information currently.

Comment: please update here once/if something like this is available